# How to send a string to the memory of the graphics card through a loop?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader

I want to send "Hello world" to the memory of the graphics card, the code is as follows:

```
section MBR vstart=0x7C00
    ...
    mov ax, 0xB800
    mov gs, ax

    ...

    mov cx, 0
    mov bx, 0
    cmp cx, STRLEN
    jl cycle
    jmp end
    cycle:
        mov byte ah, [MESSAGE + cx]
        mov [gs:(0x00 + bx)], ah
        mov [gs:(0x00 + bx + 1)], STYLE
        add bx, 2
        add cx, 1
        cmp cx, STRLEN
        jl cycle

    end:
        jmp $

MESSAGE db "Hello World!"
STRLEN equ $ - MESSAGE
; Set the text attribute, A means the green background flashes, 4 means the foreground color is red
STYLE equ 0xA4
times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xAA
```

This is an MBR program, and when I compile it through nasm, I get this error:

```
mbr.asm:47: error: invalid effective address
```

Line 47 is `mov byte ah, [MESSAGE + cx]`.

How can I send a string to the graphics card's memory through a loop?